# Showing that the Sierpinski's Carpet is path-connected.

Tags: general-topology, fractals, path-connected

I'm trying to show the path-connectedness of the [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_carpet) and so far all I got is that at any iteration the sides of the carpet are always gonna be there so if there is a path from a point to any edge then it should be path-connected. However, I can't seem to formulate such a path. Can anyone give a hint or guide me in the right direction?